# what's different between “head to” and “head for”？

Tags: prepositions

in what context should I use these two phrase ?

e.g.

He is headed to town.
He is headed for town.

Answer (score 2):

I will use your examples to tell you the way I distinguish between the scenarios for when to use to/for:

1. He is headed to town means the person is going in the
   direction of the town. It doesn't necessarily mean the end goal of
   the person is the town.
2. He is headed for town means that the person is going in the direction of 
   the town and the end goal of that person is to reach that town.

This distinction works for me. Here is the article for a much more detailed answer. http://languagelore.net/2009/05/head-for-vs-head-to/